# Publishing SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

i trying to publish SharePoint workflow 2013 and i got the following error message during publishing process:

Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Server stack trace: 
   at Sys

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this error a few times. One solution that seems to work about 75% of the time is to clear your SharePoint Designer cache. Sometimes Designer gets out of sync which can cause this issue. I have appended a resource that has directions on how to accomplish this.

[How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)